# serverless-plugin-split-stacks: Unresolved resource dependencies [DistBucketParameter]

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless

I am building a serverless app with server-side rendered React. I have based my app on this boilerplate: https://github.com/arabold/serverless-react-boilerplate. I have a lot of functions, more than 100 amounting to more than 700 cloud formation resources.
I added serverless-plugin-split-stacks to get around the 200 resource limit. Once I added it I started getting the following error:

```
Error:
CREATE_FAILED: 12NestedStack (AWS::CloudFormation::Stack)
Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [DistBucketParameter] in the Resources block of the template
```

I read all the other similar issues, but could not find a solution, my serverless.yml:

```
...
custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, "dev"}
  serverless-offline:
    noAuth: true
    useChildProcesses: true
    noPrependStageInUrl: true
    httpPort: 3000
    lambdaPort: 3002
    websocketPort: 3001
  # from boilerplate
  distBucketUrl:
    us-east-1:
      # us-east-1 uses a different URL format than the other regions
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - https://s3.amazonaws.com/
          - Ref: DistBucket
    default:
      # All other regions
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - https://s3-
          - Ref: AWS::Region
          - .amazonaws.com/
          - Ref: DistBucket
  splitStacks:
    nestedStackCount: 20 # Controls the number of created nested stacks
    perFunction: false
    perType: false
    perGroupFunction: true

  scripts:
    hooks:
      # Build the client-side script before packaging backend code
      package:initialize: "npm run build:browser"
      deploy:finalize: "npx sls s3deploy --stage ${self:provider.stage}"

  webpack:
    webpackConfig: "webpack.server.config.js"

  assets:
    # Automatically copy distribution folder to S3 stopped working; do it manually (see `scripts.hooks.deploy:finalize`)
    auto: false
    targets:
      - bucket:
          Ref: DistBucket
        acl: public-read
        files:
          - source: dist/
            headers:
              CacheControl: max-age=31104000 # 1 year
            globs:
              - "**/*"

apiGateway:
  shouldStartNameWithService: true # for upcoming Serverless v3

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  memorySize: 512
  timeout: 30
  logRetentionInDays: 7
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221 # for upcoming Serverless v3
  environment:
    SERVERLESS_PROJECT: ${self:service}
    SERVERLESS_REGION: ${self:provider.region}
    SERVERLESS_STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    APP_DIST_URL: ${self:custom.distBucketUrl.${self:provider.region}, self:custom.distBucketUrl.default}
    APP_PUBLIC_URL: ${self:custom.distBucketUrl.${self:provider.region}, self:custom.distBucketUrl.default}
    APIGATEWAY_URL:
      Fn::Join:
        - ""
        - - https://
          - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
          - .execute-api.
          - Ref: AWS::Region
          - .amazonaws.com/
          - ${self:provider.stage}

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-split-stacks
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-plugin-scripts
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-s3-deploy

resources:
  Resources:
    # Customize the API Gateway resource
    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        # Enable gzip compression
        MinimumCompressionSize: 1000

    # S3 Bucket for the distribution bundles
    DistBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      DeletionPolicy: Delete
      Properties:
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            - AllowedHeaders:
                - "*"
              AllowedMethods:
                - "GET"
              AllowedOrigins:
                - Fn::Join:
                    - ""
                    - - https://
                      - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
                      - .execute-api.
                      - Ref: AWS::Region
                      - .amazonaws.com
              MaxAge: 3000

  Outputs:
    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Description: API Gateway Endpoint
      Value:
        Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
    DistBucket:
      Description: Distribution S3 Bucket
      Value:
        Ref: DistBucket

functions:
  serve:
    # Any web request regardless of path or method will be handled by a single Lambda function
    handler: handler.serve
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: any
          cors: true
      - http:
          path: /{any+}
          method: any
          cors: true
```

Relevant package versions:

```
"serverless": "^3.38.0",
"serverless-jest-plugin": "^0.4.0",
"serverless-offline": "^13.3.0",
"serverless-plugin-scripts": "^1.0.2",
"serverless-prune-plugin": "^2.0.2",
"serverless-plugin-split-stacks": "^1.13.0",
"serverless-s3-deploy": "^0.10.1",
```